# how to add full width ripple effect with some margin around it in android

Tags: android, effects, ripple

I don't know how to explain my problem to you. so I start explaining.
now I have one item, on clicking that item I want to to do something . all works fines. but the problem is ripple effect start or finish with some margin. Because I want to add some margin from around.

I don't want to waste your time by just reading. so I show you some images.

[image: expecting result]

### here in above image i shows you ripple effect on account switch option of my youtube app. this is i want to do.

[image: problem image]

### here in above image I want to make ripple effect full width even i add some margins around item like youtube does this.

so how can I achieve the same thing which youtube does?

sorry for less writing my problem but above images tells my problem and you can also understand my problem by seeing this images.

Comment: Use `layout_margin`.

Comment: i already do but ripple effect start/end from margin(added margin) not from device width.

Comment: are you saying Rect ripple going out of the view bounds ?

Comment: i am using "?attr/selectableItemBackground" attribute .

Comment: Yeah thats what it .  I am saying set left and right margin to your view and see the output .

Comment: ohhhhhh. i made one mistake. the mistake is i add margin to recyclerview which is wrong (now realized). the right is we have to add margin to root layout of single item xml layout. any way thanks for answering.

Comment: You got it ... Sayonara ..

Comment: yes. sir . thanks for answering. i don't how i did this mistake. anyway at the all works well.